# Do i need to create separate script-file for each model width Backbone.js?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I just start ro study Backbone.js and i want to know: do I need to create a separate script-file for each model width Backbone.js? I have just 3 models and i can put them in one file but i think that it's incorrect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can keep all models, (and for that matter, Controllers and Views) in a single file. BUT, as a best practice it is advised to write them in different files.

Makes your code more manageable and in the end you can always bundle the files into a single file.